# Is it possible to turn off IIS compression from application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, compression

We've run into a problem with IIS compression screwing up IE6. We are stuck on a shared host and we can't turn compression off at the server level. Is it possible for us to turn off IIS compression from our ASP.Net application?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you are able to use URL rewriting...

https://serverfault.com/questions/31664/how-can-i-disable-compression-for-specific-user-agents-in-iis6